# What is know about the transcendence of inverse trigonometry and inverse hyperbolic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

I found on this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number

that $\sin a, \cos a, \tan a$ are transcendental numbers for $a \neq 0$ and algebraic. But there's no mention about their inverse, $\arcsin, \arccos, \arctan$.

I will also include $\operatorname{arcsinh}, \operatorname{arccosh}, \operatorname{arctanh}.$

Comment: If $\arcsin x$ is algebraic for some $x$, then $\sin(\arcsin x)=x$  is trascendental.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x$ is algebraic and $y=\arcsin(x)$ is algebraic as well. Then because of $\sin(y)=x$ with algebraic $y$ and $x$ we can conclude $y=0$. Therefore $\arcsin(x)$ is either $0$ or transcendental for algebraic $x$. Analogue you can show this for the other inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: I think this can also be used for the hyperbolic functions, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Is the arcsin of a transcedental number algebraic? Since the the sin of a algebraic number is transcedental.

Comment: I have no specific counterexample, but I am pretty sure that it is not in general.